# ironWorker not inserting to my database

Tags: database, laravel-4, php-5.6, iron.io, ironworker

How to connect iron.io to my `UserController.php`? Im using `app/views`.

My code in `app/views/iron/hello_worker.php`

```
    <?php
    // Worker code can be anything you want.
    echo "Starting HelloWorker at ".date('r')."\n";
    echo "payload:";
    $payload = getPayload();
    print_r($payload);

    $test = new Tests;
    $test->content = "iron.io testing";
    $test->save(); 


    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        echo "Sleep $i\n";
        sleep(1);
    }
    echo "HelloWorker completed at ".date('r');
   ?>
```

I have made it work, but it has error in iron.io dashboard `PHP Fatal error: Class 'Tests' not found in /mnt/task/hello_worker.php on line 8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you upload 1 file or entire project? You have to upload entire project.
Also take a look at [this packet](https://github.com/iron-io/laraworker).